# Get the 3 closest values some given number in a list?

Tags: clojure

Given a list of integers, find the 3 closest values to a given number.

```
=> (def mylist '(3 6 7 8 9 12 14))
=> (get_closest mylist 10)
(8 9 12)
```

Comment: Notice that the first line is not a valid Clojure code. `list` is a function, so don't use it as a symbol. Also, to declare a list you should put a single quote in front of it (in order to tell Clojure that this is data and not a function call). Last but not least, the parenthesis do not match. You could write this line as `(def my-list '(3 6 7 8 9 12 14))` or `(def my-list (list 3 6 7 8 9 12 14))` by using the `list` function explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(letfn [(closest [a b]
            (take 3 (sort-by #(Math/abs (- % b)) a)))]
    (let [a '(3 6 7 8 9 12 14)]
        (closest a 10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @akond's answer, but as a general function:

```
(defn closest [x n coll]
  "Return a list of the n items of coll that are closest to x"
  (take n (sort-by #(Math/abs (- x %)) coll)))

(closest 4 3 (range 10))
; => (4 3 5)
```

Notice that if `coll` is a Java array `sort-by` might modify it.